# Transfer between different e wallet

Tags: wallet

Can we transfer cyptocurrency to anyone so long they  hold an e-wallet, even in different part of the world?

Comment: Maybe you want to be a bit more specific in your question... Short answer is yes. You have a bitcoin wallet in Africa, I have one in Asia, and we are both connected to the internet - then we can transfer funds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so long as both parties have wallets that support the same specific cryptocurrency - e.g. both support Bitcoin (BTC).

The two parties do not have to use the same wallet software. For example, one might use a bitcoin-core wallet and the other might use an Electrum wallet. It doesn't matter.

Physical location is irrelevant - though local laws may affect parties to the transaction.

Remember that cryptocurrency transfers are usually irrevocable - you cannot cancel or reverse the treansaction if you change your mind or discover that the recipient is a liar, cheat or fraudster.